# Парсинг блока See Also в Википедии

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

ищу позможность прасить статьи в Википедии и не смог спарсить блок "See Also".  Точнее не могу найти тег по которому можна вытянуть данный блок, с названиями и ссылками.
Хочу сделать парсер для любого языка.

Какой есть способ вытянуть данный блок?

Использую Java + JSOUP

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решил при помощи парсинга JSON.
Википедия возвращает JSON по ссылке:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=TeamViewer

Чтобы получить содержание определоной секции например содержания:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=links&page=TeamViewer&section=5

Единственный минус данного способа, если нету содержания то не будет работать.

Для примера:

- Данная статья имеет содержаниия и можно парсить:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=TeamViewer

- Здесь нету содержания и соответсвено в части "sections" пусто:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&prop=sections&page=Voice%20chat

Данные ссылки возвращают JSON с названияями гиперссылок